# Form with random number as validation

Tags: php

The following PHP code is for generating a random number of four digits (**`$numero`**) and using it as a validation for a simple HTML form with three input boxes. The last input box is for entering the code (the random number). If the user doesn't write the right number in that last input box the program skips its purpose, which is adding some text to a database (**`agregar.txt`**). I think the code is fine, except for **`if ($_POST['password'] != $numero) {`**. Should I change it to a string or use another kind of variable? Each time I run the code it acts as if **`$numero`** was different from **`password`**, and I'm sure I'm writing the right number. Please some help.

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<h2>Agregar entradas a diccionarioie</h2>

<?php
// RANDOM FOUR DIGITS NUMBER
$numero = rand(1000, 9999);
echo "<b>Código: </b><big>".$numero."</big><p>";
if ($_POST['password'] != $numero) {
?>

<form name="form" method="post" action="">
<input title=" LEMA " size="30" type="text" name="lema" autofocus><br>
<input title=" TRADUCCIÓN " size="30" type="text" name="trad"><br>
<input title=" CÓDIGO " size="30" type="text" name="password"><br>
Gracias por colaborar <input title=" ENVIAR " type="submit" value="•"></form>

<?php
} else {
$lema = $_POST['lema'];
$trad = $_POST['trad'];
// ADDING TEXT TO A DATABASE
$texto = $lema." __ ".$trad."\n";
$docu = fopen("agregar.txt", "a+");
fwrite($docu, $texto);
fclose($docu);
}
?>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How could the two possibly match when you're generating a new value for `$numero` on every page load (including form submit)?

Comment: This is a typical thing we see so often: since so many "getting started" guides show examples where form and form processing code are mixed into a single script everyone is stumbling about such stupid issues. _Stop that stupid habbit!_ Place html form and the processing code in separate scripts!

Comment: assign the random number to a session array and to a hidden input, then destroy it once they match. Your logic is way off and need to refactor your entire code. You should also be getting an undefined index notice upon initial page load.

Comment: Fred -ii- : How do I assign the random number to a session array? Please be patient and explain that to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Fred -ii-, the problem in your code is the `$numero` get generated to different random number when you submit the form. The solution is to use session: [PHP session example](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

The session can be used to store your `$numero` value after the form being submitted. Here's the updated code:

```
<?php

// Make sure to start the session before any output.
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_SESSION['numero']) && $_POST['password'] == $_SESSION['numero']) {
    unset($_SESSION['numero']);
    $lema = $_POST['lema'];
    $trad = $_POST['trad'];
    // ADDING TEXT TO A DATABASE
    $texto = $lema." __ ".$trad."\n";
    $docu = fopen("agregar.txt", "a+");
    fwrite($docu, $texto);
    fclose($docu);
} else {
    // RANDOM FOUR DIGITS NUMBER & STORE IT IN SESSION.
    $numero = $_SESSION['numero'] = rand(1000, 9999);
?>
<html>
<body>
    <center>
        <h2>Agregar entradas a diccionarioie</h2>
        <b>Código: </b><big><?php echo $numero; ?></big><p>
        <form name="form" method="post" action="">
            <input title="LEMA " size="30" type="text" name="lema" autofocus><br>
            <input title="TRADUCCIÓN " size="30" type="text" name="trad"><br>
            <input title="CÓDIGO " size="30" type="text" name="password"><br>
            Gracias por colaborar <input title=" ENVIAR " type="submit" value="•">
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
<?php }
```

Just make sure that you call `session_start()` before any output (in your case the HTML document).

Hope this help.

Comment: ♦ Risan Bagja Pradana ▬ Thanks a lot! It works perfectly. I will study your code. It's going to be useful for many other beginners too.